# Matched biased transistor circuit

Tags: transistors

[image]

Hi,

I've a question, what is the role of the capacitor C in this circuit? What should be capacity of this element, and how can i find/calculate the voltage gain of this circuit ? Thanks for reply :)

Comment: It's a DC-blocking capacitor.  Values from 0.1uF to 1uF are usually used with larger values allowing more low-frequency signals through.

Comment: And how can find voltage gain of this circuit ? I guess it is a transistor based amplifier, am I right?

Comment: In principle, it is possible to derive a FORMULA for the gain expression (involving beta). For a gain VALUE we need the betas for both transistors.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the current in Q2 we need to first determine the bias for Q1.

If we make an assumption that the voltage across Q1 is 0.7V.  The current through the 180 ohm resistor in Q1 emitter is (20-0.7)/(20000+180) = 0.95mA.

The same current will flow through Q2 because of symmetry.

The effective emitter resistance of Q2 will be 1000/(40*0.95)+180 = 206 ohms

The gain for Q2 will be Rc/Re = 10000/206 = 48.5.

This neglects Early effect, parasitic capacitances and assumes that C is large enough to have negligible impedance at the frequency of operation.

Comment: Well, I'm late here and another question lead me here. ANyway, you talk about symmetry here. What kind of symmetry it is? Is it any parameters symmetry or just how the circuit looks?